# Renaming output to reflect name of input using ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder, naming-conventions

Every quarter I will be replacing the two CSV files at the beginning of the model. I would like the final Excel file and feature class to each have a name that reflects the input CSV file name (please see model below). For the example below, I would like to have them renamed as: 2015Q1, as a reflection of the names of the input CSV files.

Is this possible to do?

I am not using 'iteration', which most of the similar questions are referring to.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend the [Parse Path](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//004000000008000000) tool in ModelBuilder.  Make sure to select the "Name" parse type.  In this (very simplified) model, I included a "workspace" variable that I can call at any point and combine with the name value from the parse path output.  The syntax for that would be `%Workspace%\%Value%` in the output path parameter.  You should also attach a [precondition](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002w0000007r000000) so that the parse path tool is in sync with the rest of the model.

[image]

Comment: How do I add a jpg (screenshot) here in comments?
@Aaron, I tried Parse Path, connecting it from "2015Q1_B.csv" to both "copy features" and "table to excel". Neither one worked in modifying the final names.
I had selected the "Name" parse type. I did not add workspace as I did not think it necessary (I could be wrong though). I used the preconditions as in your example.

Comment: You would want to attach Parse Path to the input variable "2015Q1_B.CSV".  Then simply attach `%Value%` to any output path (e.g. `C:\path\to\some\folder\%Value%`. A precondition may not be necessary if you are not iterating through features.

Comment: I tried what you suggested but received an error message: _ERROR 000210: Cannot create output: E:\GIS\Locations.gdb\2015Q1_B. Failed to execute (Copy Features (2))._

Comment: Did you specify "Name" in the parse path tool?

Comment: Yes, I specified "NAME" in the parse type in Parse Path. Is there an issue with including '%' in a gdb pathname?

Comment: I just ran another test on my end and all worked as expected.  I would advise you to create a very simple model to test this method out and go from there.  Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce your error.